# why is fixed position messing up my alignment?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to keep the header still and have the rest of the content scroll underneath it. I am able to achieve this, however when I put a fixed position on my two header divs the break out of the margin auto.

css:

```
.structure {
    width:960px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    background:#121212;
    border-left:5px #F06BA8 solid;
    border-right:5px #F06BA8 solid;
}
.header_home_structure {
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    position:fixed;
    height:80px;
}
.header_home_bg {
    width:100%;
    background:#121212;
    border-bottom:3px #F06BA8 solid;
    height:80px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="header_home_bg clearfix">
        <div class="header_home_structure clearfix">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="structure clearfix">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `position: fixed` on the container div, don't use it twice

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/B2m2h/)

```
.structure {
    width:960px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    background:#121212;
    border-left:5px #F06BA8 solid;
    border-right:5px #F06BA8 solid;
}
.header_home_structure {
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    height:80px;
}
.header_home_bg {
    width:100%;
    background:#121212;
    border-bottom:3px #F06BA8 solid;
    height:80px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: He will probably also want to add margin-top: 80px to .structure so the fixed header doesn't overlap it.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert ya I expect that much from him..than too a good point, moreover I don't understand how a fixed div can break his layout